# How to find the inverse for the inverse sampling method in R

Tags: r, probability, sampling, inverse-transform

Generally for the inverse sampling method, we have a density and we would like to sample from it. A first step is to find the the cumulative density function for the density. Then to find it's inverse, and finally to find the inverse function for a randomly sampled value from the uniform distribution.

For example, I have this function `y= ((3/2)/(1+x)^2)` so the cdf equals `(3x)/2(x+1)` and the inverse of the cdf is `((3/2)*u)/(1-(3/2)*u)`

To do this in R, I wrote

```
 f<-function(x){
 y= ((3/2)/(1+x)^2)
 return(y)
}



cdf <- function(x){
  integrate(f, -Inf, x)$value
}

invcdf <- function(q){
  uniroot(function(x){cdf(x) - q}, range(x))$root
}
U <- runif(1e6)
X <- invcdf(U)
```

I have two problem! First: the code returns the function and not the samples.
The second: is there another simple way to do this work? for example to find the cdf and inverse in more simple ways?

I would like to add that I am not looking for efficiency of the code. I am just interested of a code that could be written by a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a numerical approach to inverse sampling. As per your request, this is more about transparency of method than efficiency.

This function will numerically integrate a given function over the given range (though it will trim infinite values)

```
cdf <- function(f, lower_bound, upper_bound)
{
  if(lower_bound < -10000) lower_bound <- -10000          # Trim large negatives
  if(upper_bound > 10000) upper_bound <- 10000            # Trim large positive
  x <- seq(lower_bound, upper_bound, length.out = 100001) # Finely divide x axis
  delta <- mean(diff(x))                                  # Get delta x (i.e. dx)
  mid_x <- (x[-1] + x[-length(x)])/2                      # Get the mid point of each slice
  result <- cumsum(delta * f(mid_x))                      # sum f(x) dx
  result <- result / max(result)                          # normalize
  list(x = mid_x, cdf = result)                           # return both x and f(x) in list
}
```

And to get the inverse, we find the closest value in the cdf of a random number drawn from the uniform distribution between 0 and 1. We then see which value of x corresponds to that value of the cdf. We want to be able to do this for n samples at a time so we use `sapply`:

```
inverse_sample <- function(f, n = 1, lower_bound = -1000, upper_bound = 1000)
{
  CDF <- cdf(f, lower_bound, upper_bound)
  samples <- runif(n)
  sapply(samples, function(s) CDF$x[which.min(abs(s - CDF$cdf))])
}
```

We can test it by drawing histograms of the results. We'll start with the normal distribution's density function (`dnorm` in R), drawing 1000 samples and plotting their distribution:

```
hist(inv_sample(dnorm, 1000))
```

[image]

And we can do the same for the exponential distribution, this time setting the limits of integration between 0 and 100:

```
hist(inv_sample(dexp, 1000, 0, 100))
```

[image]

And finally we can do the same with your own example:

```r
f <- function(x) 3/2/(1 + x)^2

hist(inv_sample(f, 1000, 0, 10))
```

[image]